# Visualizing daily Event schedule with WPF

Tags: calendar, time, wpf

I am in conceptual phase of a little utility to help our support team identify what is about to happen, and what should have happened but didn't.

basically our system is scheduled to do many things. Sometimes during a problem, events are missed or delayed.

i have a list of running processes ~50-100. these processes each have a separate schedule of when they activate. I want to illustrate what's about to happen and what has missed the schedule. i'd like to be able to show this for 1 or many processes.

my first thought, is a simple grid (or vertical items list) that shows vertically audit style of rows, with their color gradually faded the further into the future they are, and red when missed. possibly have a time indicator on either side, to show where we are now, and what's coming next. but this may be tricky if multiple processes are shown.

alternatively, i could minimize each scheduled event into a process ID, as we're all familiar with those ID's , to be able to fit more items into a screen (and/or show them horizontally). I am not aware of how this could easily be done with WPF.

i'd like to do this using standard WPF 4.0 as that's at my disposal.

can someone suggest some common layouts for above? maybe something similar already accomplished in WPF?

Comment: It would be helpful if you said what you meant by WPF.  TLAs can be confusing.

Comment: Windows Presentation Foundation

Answer (score 1):

You could always take a look at Code Project [WPF Data Matrix](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37241/Displaying-a-Data-Matrix-in-WPF) implementation, which is a good start. If that doesn't taste well, there is the free [Book of WPF](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFPresents/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3536) to turn to. It's a Microsoft production, which contain som good examples of layout ideas.